# Make a loop wait until button has been pressed to continue in JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a HTML5 app and here is what I want to do:

I want to create a loop which for which as long as x is smaller than y, it will pause, ask a user for input, and once the user inputs something, it will check if x is smaller than y, pause and ask the user for input....until x is no longer smaller than y.

I want the input to be buttons from the Framework7 action sheet: http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/action-sheet.html#.VFhLMBb4oUM So I want the loop to wait until the user presses one of those buttons.

Is this possible to do in Jquery or JavaScript?

----Extra Info-----

The program runs, a user inputs words (we'll call this w), once he/she does that and clicks a button. After this, the input is separated into an array where each word is a different value (call this array words). I have an array which stores the words and also what parts of speech they are. The user will determine what part of speech they are.

I want a loop or event (both) to fire which something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<words.length){
var buttons = [
    {
        text: 'What is "'+listandtypes[0][i]+'"', //word
        label: true
    },
    {
        text: 'Adjective',
        onClick: function () {
            listandtypes[1][i] = "adj"; //part of speech
            myApp.alert('Button1 clicked');
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Adverb',
        onClick: function () {
            listandtypes[1][i] = "adv";
            myApp.alert('Button2 clicked');
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Noun',
        onClick: function () {
            listandtypes[1][i] = "noun";
            myApp.alert('Button2 clicked');
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Verb',
        onClick: function () {
            listandtypes[1][i] = "verb";
            myApp.alert('Button2 clicked');
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Other',
        color: 'red',
        onClick: function () {
            listandtypes[1][i] = "idk";
            myApp.alert('Cancel clicked');
        }
    },
];
myApp.actions(buttons);
        } //I want this loop to wait until a button is pressed
//More code
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot, as the button press is asynchronous. Rewrite your function to a recursive one, and call the next "iteration" from the button's click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out how to do this (special thanks to @Bergi for recommending this):

```
function selectWords(){

        var buttons = [
        {
            text: 'What is "'+listandtypes[0][thecurrentnum]+'"',
            label: true
        },
        {
            text: 'Adjective',
            onClick: function () {
                listandtypes[1][thecurrentnum] = "adj";
                thecurrentnum = thecurrentnum + 1;
                if(thecurrentnum < word.length){
                    selectWords();
                }
                else{
                    timer1();
                }
                console.log("Current Num: " +thecurrentnum+ ", Length: " +thecurrentnum);
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Adverb',
            onClick: function () {
                listandtypes[1][thecurrentnum] = "adv";
                thecurrentnum = thecurrentnum + 1;
                if(thecurrentnum < word.length){
                    selectWords();
                }
                else{
                    timer1();
                }
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Noun',
            onClick: function () {
                listandtypes[1][thecurrentnum] = "noun";
                thecurrentnum = thecurrentnum + 1;
                if(thecurrentnum < word.length){
                    //thecurrentnum = thecurrentnum + 1;
                    selectWords();
                }
                else{
                    timer1();
                }
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Verb',
            onClick: function () {
                listandtypes[1][thecurrentnum] = "verb";
                thecurrentnum = thecurrentnum + 1;
                if(thecurrentnum < word.length){
                    //thecurrentnum = thecurrentnum + 1;
                    selectWords();
                }
                else{
                    timer1();
                }
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Other',
            color: 'red',
            onClick: function () {
                listandtypes[1][thecurrentnum] = "idk";
                thecurrentnum = thecurrentnum + 1;
                if(thecurrentnum < word.length){
                    //thecurrentnum = thecurrentnum + 1;
                    selectWords();
                }
                else{
                    timer1();
                }
            }
        },
    ];
    myApp.actions(buttons);
}
```